# Message backend for android app

Tags: android, backend

I'm developing an android app with chat feature. The question is how should i do backend? Should it be like a msg socket or http REST API? There are a lot of apps with such feature (e.g. facebook), so it should be some classical solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not too clear. But I guess you are in the planning stage. So if you want it to work like a chat application on Android, you want to use GCM. And for GCM you can have an [HTTP Server](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) like Apache,Nginx or any other server of your choice, or you can have a [CCS Server](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) . REST or not, is your choice, but it's better to use CCS server for chat application where bidirectional communication between server and client required.

[Here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Building-a-Chat-Application) is a tutorial on Samsung Developer Site.

Comment: Yes, it's planning stage. The question is "is it better to have open socket or request server with some short timeout". Basicly it's about powersaving.

Comment: But seems like CCS Server is the answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it gave you some direction :)